# Recording Internal GPS coordinates in Terrasync

Tags: gps, trimble, pathfinder, terrasync

I work in the exploration department of a mining company. We use a Trimble receiver to record the locations of our drill holes. We also use the Trimble handheld to record the handheld's internal GPS data in order to verify the Trimble pickup.

Problem is, we don't know how to record the internal GPS data so it can be synced to Pathfinder along with the Trimble receiver data.

Is there a way to do this on Terrasync?

At the moment, we are manually typing the GPS coordinates into our toughbooks. This leads to typos.

Answer (score 1):

Terrasync. . .  It's been a while.

Since you mention "toughbook", I assume that's a Panasonic?  Assuming that your Toughbook model provides NMEA output on a serial port you could do something like this in TerraSync (this is just a proof of concept, but it will demonstrate the solution):

- Connect to the external Trimble GNSS as normal
- Select Setup / External Sensors
- Enable Sensor 1 and click on the corresponding Properties button
- Select the port number for NMEA output from the Toughbook internal GNSS
- Set the Baud rate , data bits, etc, to appropriate values (if it's a Virtual Com Port, the baud rate etc. don't matter)
- Set the prefix String to GGA  (to pick up NMEA GGA sentences)
- Set the Suffix string to * (to end capture with the start of NMEA checksum)
- Set Max Bytes to 240
- Set Time Out to 0.5 seconds
- Leave receive mode set to "Unsolicited"
- Set logging interval for Point feature = 1s
- Set logging interval for Line / Area feature = Off
- Set logging interval for Not in Feature = Off
- Set data destination = As Attribute
- Enter Attribute name "Comment" (later, you will change this to an attribute of your choice)
- Hit OK / OK etc. to exit and save

When you open a data file, TerraSync will try to open the Com port you specified for the Sensor.  When you create a Point Feature and start logging positions, the GGA sentence will appear in the Comment field (with the "GGA" prefix and "*" suffix removed), updated every second (I guess the last value will be stored.)  To see whether this is working, select Status / Sensor while you are collecting a Point feature, you should see something like ",000645.00,4332.71420812,S,17235" displayed for Sensor1.

After ending the feature and closing the SSF file, transferring to PC, opening the SSF file in Pathfinder office, select the feature and look at the comment attribute - for my example, this is ",000645.00,4332.71420812,S,17235".  That would be the start of the NMEA GGA sentence, so UTC Time = 00:06:45, Lat = 43°32.71420812 S, Long = 172°35 - and the rest is truncated because the Comment attribute is only 32 characters long.

Left for you to do:

- Use some NMEA-capable or terminal utility (Terraterm?) to confirm that the toughbook does supply NMEA on some serial port
- Create your own data dictionary in PFO, adding a NMEA-GGA Text attribute which is long enough to take a full GGA string
- Modify the instructions to use the NMEA-GGA attribute instead of the Comment attribute
- If toughbook does have NMEA but it doesn't give GGA sentences, GLL and RMC also have Lat and Long so look for those.

Note:  The position given by the toughbook GNSS is likely to be a few M away from the Trimble GNSS position - this is a question of accuracy as well as reference frames.